# What's the difference between a modified method parameter and that of a copy of it in Java?

Tags: java, variables, methods, parameters, arguments

Is there any difference between these two methods?

```
public Long saveModel(Model model) {
    model.setUpdated(new Date());
    Long id = dao.save(model);
    return id;
}
```

and

```
public Long saveModel(Model model) {
    Model m = model;
    m.setUpdated(new Date());
    Long id = dao.save(m);
    return id;
}
```

Comment: look the same to me - apart from the short lived and redundant variable "m"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from a behavioral standpoint, and running both would show as much.

From a readability standpoint, the second one is IMO a bit misleading as there's an *implication* something "interesting" is happening, when there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small clarification. You're not actually copying the parameter:

```
public Long saveModel(Model model) {
    Model m = model; //Instance of the Model class that references the parameter
    m.setUpdated(new Date());
    Long id = dao.save(m);
    return id;
}
```

Instead, you're storing a new reference to the `model` parameter in `m`. I think you're talking about something related to the concepts of *Deep Copy* and *Shallow Copy* where:

- *Deep copy* implies cloning the main object and all of its inner references (in short: create new instances for every involved object).
- *Shallow copy* means cloning the main element, keeping the references to its derived elements (like copying a `Car` but having his `owner` referencing the same `owner` than the original `Car`).

Here, both methods do the same. The only difference is that additional `Model` object.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour is the same.

```
 Model m = model;
```

You are creating a local variable that refers the same like model variable. So it's not a copy. It's a reference variable copy really.

`m` and `model`  refers to the same object in heap memory

So if you change m or model for example with `set methods`

```
m.setUpdated(new Date());
model.getUpdated(); --> will get the date object you set above
```

So it's not a copy of the object itself. It's a copy of the reference variable

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference between these two methods?

They do exactly the same thing.  (They're written differently, though.)